# Use payment ids/integrated wallets in web applications

Tags: payment-id, integrated-address, payment-integration

I am developing a web application and would like every user to have there own monero address they could send XMR to, so how could I make that work in php or javascript.

Comment: While I have no suggestions about PHP or Javascript, I'll point out that subaddresses are what you're looking for. A single address, no payment IDs. They might not be supported by all software (eg, mymonero) yet though.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not clear about your web app, like will the user be sending XMR or receiving XMR?  I'm assuming they will be sending, so maybe just have one exchange address that your backend service uses and then assign payment Id to each user.  Then they don't have to see any address, just a payment Id. A stable exchange like Bittrix are up 24x7 and pretty secure.  A drawback is paying an extra fee if/when you move it to your own wallet. But if/when you cash out you need an exchange so keeping it there would be a wash then (fee wise).

Comment: Yeah I was wondering if there is an easy way to add intergated xmr addresses, one per user, in the web app